# crossfading a group of audio files with sox splice

Tags: audio, scripting, sox, piping

I am able to join and crossfade two audio files using SoX, like so:

```
sox file1.wav file2.wav outfile.wav splice -q `soxi -D file1.wav`,0.5
```

where the soxi substitution is fetching the duration of file1 and 0.5 is the length of the cross-fade. I am now trying to extend this to an arbitrary number of files, in order to string them together with short crossfades in between. There would seem to be 2 approaches: piping and scripting. Sox has a -p option telling it to treat it's output as piped (instead of writing a file). But, with many input and arguments per command, it's not clear how that output ([and input?](http://linuxmoc.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/vox-recording-in-linux-part-2/#comments)) gets assigned in subsequent commands. So far I've got the line below, which **does not work**, trying to extend to 3 files.

```
sox -p file1.wav file2.wav splice -q `soxi -D file1.wav`,0.5 | sox -p file3.wav outfile.wav splice -q `soxi -D file3.wav`,0.5
```

Your tips on sox piping and scripting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Despite the fact that this is an old question, I'm providing a reference to a working solution for those that stumble across it: You can use the method as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652490/cross-fading-several-audio-files-using-sox/28670099#28670099) to crossfade multiple files into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have gotten most of the way there with

```
sox --combine concatenate *.wav _merge.wav splice -q 3,1
```

The splice effect at the end places the beginning of the cross-fade at 3 seconds into the first file, and uses 1 second as cross-fade duration (half second at beginning and end of two files). This method is a temporary fix as I can choose to include only ~3 second files in my output (using other methods). 
A better answer would figure out how to grab duration of current file and substitute that in place of the 3.

```
sox --combine concatenate *.wav _merge.wav splice -q $(soxi −D {}),1
```

If the {} here selected the current item (as in `find`), that would do it. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, this dont work, any chance that you find solution for crossfading banch of files. Thanx, im desperate to do this kind o batch, got so many file to process.Please help

Comment: this answer helped me put a fixed length intro on a recording automatically. Thanks!